# autocomplete search in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Hy, i am making an autocomplete search field in codeigniter,

Here is my view:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js" ></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function(){
        $( "#text" ).autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost/new/index.php/travels/search_fields",
                data: { term: $("#text").val()},
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                success: function(data){
                    response(data);
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form method="post">
 <input type="text" name="text" id="text" autocomplete="off" > 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my controller:

```
    function search_fields(){
    $term = $this->input->post('term', TRUE);   
    $data['var']= $this->Travel->search_field($term); 
    echo json_encode($data['var']); 

}
```

and here is my model:

```
 function search_field($term){
    $this->db->distinct();
    $this->db->select("destination");
    $this->db->from('travels_detail');
    $this->db->like('destination', $term);
     $this->db->group_by('travels_detail.destination');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();

}
```

I am getting an empty drop down list, where I am doing wrong??  is there anything wrong with ajax or library etc. Please anyone help me out.

Comment: before `response(data);` line use `console.log(data)` and show this. let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Model return `result_array` :

```
return $query->result_array();
```

In Controller :

```
$search_data = $this->Travel->search_field($term); 
echo json_encode($search_data);
```

Some change after ajax success :

```
success: function(data){
   var resp = $.map(data,function(obj){
        return obj.destination;
   }); 
   response(resp);
}
```

Comment: thanx @razib al mamun